# When I compile my project I got an error: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

Tags: java, spring, maven

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http:\www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc]

How to fix it?

Comment: Please use the search function. There are a lot of similar questions on SO (see the "Related" column on the right) and I'm sure you'll be able to find the answer you want there.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using spring 3.0x, check if the spring-jdbc-3.0 jars are correctly placed in the WEB-INF lib folder.

This is mostly a dependency issue, check if the pom.xml file has the correct dependency of the spring jdbc related jars...

Answer (score 1):

It might be a related jar that is missing but the exception shows a weird namespace url:

> `http:\www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc`

You should check your xml configuration file and make sure you have the following namespace declaration:

```
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
```

and the following schemaLocation:

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
```

Or point directly here to always have the latest version of the xsd:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building and assembling with maven. I fixed this adding some transformers to the **maven-shade-plugin**

These both transforms did the trick and the error was gone:

```
<transformer
      implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer
      implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the version of my spring dependencies (spring-jdbc, spring-tx) from version 4.X.X to 3.X.X